# When did instance URL format change for some sandboxes to now to <domain name>.sandbox.my.saleforce.com/services/apexrest

Tags: sandbox-refresh, mydomain, release-notes, enhanced-domains

I can't pinpoint at what point/why the instance URL changed for my full copy sandbox. It now has .sandbox added to the instance URL but not all of my sandboxes have this change yet. We have My Domain enabled so for example if my domain name was 'codey' and sandbox name was 'full' the instance URL has changed from "https://codey--full.my.salesforce.com" to "https://codey--full.sandbox.my.salesforce.com" after performing authorization request.

I'm also confused as to why my full copy sandbox has this change to add .sandbox while my developer pro sandbox does not. I could see it being a recent release but haven't found this in any release notes yet and doesn't explain why some sandboxes have it while others don't. I did confirm that production and all sandboxes are on the same Summer '22 Patch 13.5 release. It would be good to be able to prepare for this change in the dev pro sandbox.

The other thing I can think of is a recent refresh of the full copy sandbox from Prod but I still have the question of what documentation would cite this change to the URL.

Comment: Thanks for posting about this. Recently my Force.com Toolkit C#-to-SFDC-API authentication stopped working because I wasn't aware of this domain/url change. Once I added "sandbox" to my endpoint_login (url) my authentication started working again.

Answer (score 3):

It would appear someone enabled [Enhanced Domains](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_domains_enhanced_ru.htm&type=5&release=238) in that sandbox if it's the only one with that behavior. I would also check whether it's enabled in Production and this was the first sandbox refreshed since that change which would also explain that change.

The [Plan for Salesforce Domain Changes: My Domain and Enhanced Domains](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000358662&type=1) contains the specifics of this change that match what you're seeing

> Enhanced domains are the next version of My Domain. With this feature, all URLs across your org contain your company-specific My Domain name, including URLs for your Experience Cloud sites, Salesforce Sites, Visualforce pages, and content files. This feature changes domain suffixes (the part after the My Domain name) to meet the latest security standards. **Also, all sandbox URLs contain the word sandbox, making them easier to identify.**

The same is covered in [My Domain URL Format Changes When you Enable Enhanced Domains](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_url_format_changes_enable_enhanced.htm&type=5) with a specific section for Sandbox URLs.

> When you enable enhanced domains, the domain suffix—the part after the My Domain name—changes for Experience Cloud sites, Salesforce Sites, content files, Site.com Studio, Experience Builder, and Visualforce URLs. **And sandbox org URLs include the word “sandbox,” making it easy to identify a sandbox org from its URL.**

[image]

Comment: Upvoted: enabled in prod + refresh is the answer. Had this happen at some of our customers.

Comment: That was it, thank you!! Since we have multiple admins someone must have changed this without communicating to the rest of the team.